# how to count max, min, average, and median of quantity order

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called order_match which contain order_buyer_Id as the id of the transaction, createdby as the id of the buyer, and createdAt as the date when the transaction happened and quantity as the quantity of each order.

In this case, I want to count of the order (order_buyer_Id) for each buyer (createdby) and find out the maximum and the minumum count after that.

this is the example data:

```
+----------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| order_buyer_id | createdby | createdAt  |quantity|
+----------------+-----------+------------+--------+
|          19123 |        19 | 2017-02-02 |0.4     |
|         193241 |        19 | 2017-02-02 |0.5       
|         123123 |        20 | 2017-02-02 |1       |
|          32242 |        20 | 2017-02-02 |4
|          32434 |        20 | 2017-02-02 |3       |
+----------------+-----------+------------+---------
```

and if I run the query, the expected result is:

```
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
| max | min | average | median |
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
|   4 | 0.4 |    1,78 |      1 |
+-----+-----+---------+---------
```

This is the fiddle

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d89772/15

and this is my query

```
SELECT MAX(quantity) AS max,
       MIN(quantity) AS min,
       AVG(quantity) AS average,
       AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (FLOOR((@tr+1)/2), FLOOR((@tr+2)/2)) THEN quantity END) AS median
FROM (
  SELECT count, 
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @tr := @rn AS tr
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM order_match
    GROUP BY order_buyer_Id
    order by quantity
  ) o
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) init
) c
```

Comment: You need to join with the original table to get `quantity`

Comment: can you more specific what should i do in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `quantity` is not in your `subquery`.

Either you have join with your table again to get the `quantity` or you can include the quantity in you `select` *(based on your sample data even `group by` with quantity gives the same result)*

```
SELECT MAX(quantity) AS max,
       MIN(quantity) AS min,
       AVG(quantity) AS average,
       AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (FLOOR((@tr+1)/2), FLOOR((@tr+2)/2)) THEN quantity END) AS median
FROM (
  SELECT count, quantity,
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @tr := @rn AS tr
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,Quantity
    FROM order_match
    GROUP BY order_buyer_Id,Quantity
    order by quantity
  ) o
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) init
) c
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d89772/18)

Comment: thankyou very much sir, but the result of the average it's wrong, it should 18 (total amount of quantity) / 2 users or createdby (19 and 20) did you know how to change it

Comment: thankyou very much sir, the count of max and min are true, but the average was wrong, because it dont count average of total of quantity to count of users(createdby) 
based on the data dummy, the average should be 9 (total quantity 18 to 2 total users createdby)

Comment: `AVG()` function will take the overall count of your table to find the average. In your case, you can use `subquery` to get the count of users(createdby). [CHECK THIS FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d89772/29) where i have modified the query to find the count separately @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil

Comment: THANKS sir, your da best

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.max,t.min,t.average,0.00 AS 'Median'

FROM
(SELECT MAX(quantity) AS max,

       MIN(quantity) AS min,

       SUM(quantity)/COUNT(distinct created_by) AS average

FROM order_match)t

union 

SELECT 0.00 AS 'max',0.00 AS 'min',0.00 AS 'Average',

((2*t1.average/3)+t1.mode) AS 'Median' 

FROM (SELECT count(FLOOR(quantity)),IFNULL(FLOOR(quantity),min(quantity)) AS 'mode'  

FROM order_match GROUP BY quantity HAVING 

count(FLOOR(quantity))>1)t1
```